# WooCommerce - another template - based on product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In the catalog WooCommerce have two templates:

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs.php

and

/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/tabs-two.php

I would like to, on the product page, which belongs to the category of "X" was used template tabs-two.php - tabs.php template is to be used in products belonging to any other category.

Please help!

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @helgatheviking I tried. I added this script will not work. :(

Comment: @helgatheviking I would like to just tabs.php template has been changed. All the rest can remain.

Comment: So filter `woocommerce_locate_template` and look specifically for the `tabs.php` template. Review my linked answer.